# Как правильно огранизовать струтуру Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Посоветуйте как правильно организовать структуру хранения данных в монго.
Входные данные E-mail, телефон и некий уникакльный номер посетителя сайта , храниться в куке и соответственно может меняться по разным причинам( n_id).
Допустим мне приходит n_id и телефон Я создаю Документ . Во второй раз мне приходит n_id и емаил. Мне нужно проперить , по E-mail и n_id есть ли такой документ который содержит или то или то.
Если есть то дополнить его отсутствующеми данными.
Тоесть 1 документ может иметь допустим 2 номера, 10 n_id, и 5 емайл .
При думал 2 структуры хранениия, может быть посоветуете как лучше.
1.Вариант

```
{
"_id": {"$oid": "5f56a52a9eafb85d4314c612"},
"created_at": {"$date": "2020-09-07T21:24:58.766Z"},
"data": [
  {
    "phone": 77777777,
    "email": "1@1.ru",
    "n_id": 12
  },
  {
    "phone": 177777777,
    "email": "11@1.ru",
    "n_id": 112
  }
],
"updated_at": {"$date": "2020-09-07T21:24:58.766Z"}
```

}

Второй вариант

```
{
"_id": {"$oid": "5f56a5ba9eafb862c7676c02"},
"created_at": {"$date": "2020-09-07T21:27:22.454Z"},
"updated_at": {"$date": "2020-09-07T21:27:22.454Z"},
"email": ["1@1.ru", "31@1.ru"],
"n_id": [12, 112],
"phone": [77777777, 3377777777]
```

}

Comment: скажите, а в чём плюс монго; зачем  вы его выбрали?

Comment: В данном случае в скорости, и в агрегационных выборках, с кучей операций ссуммирования и группировок в 1 запросе. В mysql  выборка шла 1-2 минуты, в монго 2-10 секунд. Операции проходят по миллионным базам. Ну и плюс у ползовате я может быть неограниченное и неопределенное количетсво полей, может  ip или юсер агет, а может не быть.

Comment: любопытно ... а с постгресом не сравнивали?

Comment: Нет , пока не добрались)